# How to spread documents across shards automatically in apache solr?

Tags: solr, sharding

I have setup the core following the steps in http://carsabi.com/car-news/2012/03/23/step-by-step-solr-sharding/ . Now i am stuck at how to spread all my documents evenly among the shards created. I am not using tomcat or zookeeper. Please help. I am not able to figure out the exact steps for the setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you posted is no good. It mixes up cores and shards as though they are the same thing.

See here for difference:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology
http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/shard-versus-core-td2114829.html

ZK is your friend!

Take a look at my recent response here (recommends ElasticSearch or SolrCloud):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12180442/465710

Comment: But how can i distribute documents among different shards evenly automatically?

Comment: Isn't that done automatically in SolrCloud (you just need to specify numShards=n param)? I know that ElasticSearch works that way, by its Routing feature (document is placed in a specific shard by calculating a hash on doc's ID), so it's automatically balanced. Shards split index, while replicas share the same index.